# Irreducibility in $k((t))[y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, power-series, function-fields

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of char $0$ and suppose $f(y) \in k[y]$ (need not be monic). Let $t$ be an indeterminate and consider the fraction field $k((t))$ of power series ring $k[[t]]$. My question is:

> Is $f(y)-t$ irreducible in $k((t))[y]$?

Comment: What if $f(y)=y^2-1$? (Isn't natural to start with $f$ irreducible?)

Comment: I don’t believe that the characteristic is a significant part of this story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re in a situation where your base ring $k[[t]]=\mathfrak o$ is a complete DVR (complete local ring would be enough), and you have a polynomial $F(y)\in\mathfrak o[y]$. When you pass from $\mathfrak o$ to its residue field $\mathfrak o/\mathfrak m=k[[t]]/tk[[t]]=k$, you get a polynomial over $k$, namely $f(y)$. That is, the ring morphism $\mathfrak o\to k$ by $t\mapsto 0$ gives $F\mapsto f$.

So far, so good. I’ve tried to set your problem up so that you see that Hensel’s Lemma may apply. Now, algebraic closedness of $k$ guarantees that all irreducible factors are linear, and in case $f$ factors over $k$ into *distinct* linear factors, I mean no two are related by a constant factor, then Hensel applies,and you get a factorization of $F=f(y)-t$ into the same number of linear factors. But if there are repeats, maybe not.

Examples: $f(y)=y^n$. Then $y^n-t$ is irreducible, by Eisenstein. On the other hand, consider $y^2+y-t$, say over (the algebraic closure of) $\Bbb Q$. With a handy computation package, I see that the factorization is $(y-r_1)(y+1+r_1)$, where $r_1=t - t^2 + 2t^3 - 5t^4 + 14t^5 - 42t^6 + 132t^7 - 429t^8 +\cdots$

Comment: My example (in the comment under the question) is simpler than yours. It relies on the Taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{1+t}$ which is well known.

Comment: If we can ensure that $y^{n-1}$ coefficient of $f(y)$ is zero and $f(y) \neq y^n$,then a factorization in $k[y]$ can be lifted to a factorization in $k[[t]][y]$.This is because, if all the linear factors were same then $y^n$ coefficient is $-na$ where $a$ is a root forces $a=0$ and hence our hypothesis guarantees at least two distinct coprime factors,which will be enough to produce a reduction of $F(y)$ using Hensel's Lemma.

Comment: Yes, to both comments. The upshot is that in most cases, $f(y)-t$ will be reducible.